# Page removes from DOM when showing a dialog in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

I have a page, which contains a `<div data-role="page" ...` and a `<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog-1" ...`

And I open the dialog with this link: `<a href="#dialog-1" data-role="button"  data-rel="dialog">Open Dialog</a>`

But, there are also some links in the main `page`. For example, this is my index.html:

```
...
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="Survey">              
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="page2.html" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">Go to the next page</a>
        <a href="#dialog-1" data-role="button"  data-rel="dialog">Open Dialog</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->      
</div><!-- /page -->  
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog-1">              
    <div data-role="content">
        Welcome!
    </div><!-- /content -->      
</div><!-- /dialog-->  
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my page2.html :

```
...
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="Survey2">              
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#dialog-1" data-role="button"  data-rel="dialog">Also you can open the dialog here</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->      
</div><!-- /page -->  

</body>
</html>
```

But this is the problem: I open index.html, then click the link to go to page2.html with Ajax Navigation feature of jQuery mobile, Then click on the link `Also you can open the dialog here`. By clicking this link, **the `Survey2` page removes from the DOM.** And when I close the dialog, a new page2.html downloads and locates in the DOM.

But, **How to prevent removing page2.html from the DOM when a dialog opens?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this documentation:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html

If you want to disable the removal on `pagehide` only for the `#Survey2` page, you can add the attribute `data-dom-cache="true"` to this page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="Survey2" data-dom-cache="true">              
    <!-- [...] -->      
</div><!-- /page -->
```

If you want to keep all pages that were injected via ajax, you can enable this globally:

```
jQuery.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
```